# Timer Not working in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, timer

Timer is not working. after few second it should goto another activity

```
public class intro extends Activity {
int count=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);
    final Toast tosta = Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(count+"."), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;

                if(count == 5){
                    Intent app = new Intent("com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity");
                    startActivity(app);
                }
            tosta.show();
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);


}}
```

but after 5 sec app unfortunately has stopped.

**manifext.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jasrajcomputers"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/noactionbarvirat"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".intro"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

  </manifest>
```

**MY LOGCAT:**

```
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity }
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1697)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1492)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at com.jasrajcomputers.intro$1.run(intro.java:72)
07-12 12:46:38.979: E/AndroidRuntime(14495):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Most likely your MainActivity isn't in your manifest

Comment: Try this way : Intent app = new Intent(intro.this,MainActivity.class);

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Comment: what is the package name for MainActivity

Comment: you have two application tags in manifest. No need for that. Just declare MainActivity in the top one

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks i forgot that. thanks finally works

Comment: @Virat21 you are welcome. DO use explicit intents. Updated my post with reference to docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:theme="@style/noactionbarvirat"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".intro"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

</activity>
</application>
```

Use Explicit intents

```
Intent app = new Intent(intro.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Remove

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Update :

Timer is not required here. You can use a `Handler` instead.

Quoting docs

> Explicit intents specify the component to start by name (the
>   fully-qualified class name). You'll typically use an explicit intent
>   to start a component in your own app, because you know the class name
>   of the activity or service you want to start. For example, start a new
>   activity in response to a user action or start a service to download a
>   file in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Handler`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
     Intent app = new Intent("com.example.MainActivity");
     startActivity(app);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this code :**

```
Intent app = new Intent("com.jasrajcomputers.MainActivity");
```

**With this code :**

```
Intent app = new Intent(intro.this,MainActivity.class);
```

**Note :**

```
MainActivity must be define in AndroidManifest.xml
```